# 'Autosuggestion' feature implementation for a webapp

Tags: sql, ruby

I'm developing a web application and have two models (among others) - users and items with many-to-many association. So I have have tables 'users', 'items' and 'items_users' with primary key 'id' and foreign keys user_id and item_id.

What I'm going to have is an 'autosuggestion' feature. If, say, I'm as a user mark a certain item as good, the system is supposed to suggest n items I most probably would also mark as good. The reasonable criteria for autosuggestion is how many users who liked the first item like another one. If all users who like tea also like a teapot - then the teapot is in top position for autosuggestion.

This is basic functionality, I'll also filter some results but the rest doesn't matter. I'm thinking about some kind of an auxiliary table for fast calculation on demand or scheduling a separate process to calculate n suggestions.

Thank you for any related information!

**UPD**

The question sounded unclear. I have sql db and sinatra with sequel orm. I'm asking about how to calculate most similar items dataset (cheapest, least resourse consuming approach). How would you implement it?

Comment: So, what is your question? Recommendation engines is a very complex topic.

Comment: "How would you implement it?" - I think you should try implement it yourself first. Then you'll be able to ask a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, generally you want to select all users that liked the same products then get the products they like by counting the numer of likes for each product and output the most liked products.

So how would this look in SQL?

Let's see how would this look in SQL:

**Step 1**: Get the id's of your favourites

```
SELECT it.item_id FROM `item_users` it WHERE it.user_id = %current_user%
```

**Step 2**: Get the users who like the same items

```
SELECT u.id FROM `item_users` it, `users` u WHERE it.item_id IN (  
    SELECT it.item_id FROM `item_users` it WHERE it.user_id = %current_user%  
) AND it.user_id != %current_user% AND u.id = it.user_id GROUP BY it.user_id
```

**Step 3**: Get their favourites

And the entire SQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT i.* FROM `items` i, `item_users` it WHERE it.user_id IN (  
    SELECT u.id FROM `item_users` it, `users` u WHERE it.item_id IN (  
        SELECT it.item_id FROM `item_users` it WHERE it.user_id = %current_user%  
    ) AND it.user_id != %current_user% AND u.id = it.user_id GROUP BY it.user_id  
) AND i.id = it.item_id GROUP BY i.id ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Your task is to add limiting of the results...

**UPDATE**:
I guess that you would like to get the most populat products first. I've changed the query to add that functionality (added `ORDER BY count(*) DESC` to the end)

This is a complex query and using ActiveRecord to implement it would be quite slow and even more complicated, so I would recommend you using the query as is.

Answer (score 0):

Use your link table to join users and items.
Apply following filters in your WHERE-Clause:
- users that liked the item ("marked it as good")
- items, that the current user did not already mark as good

Sort descending by the number of likes (you'll need to group by the item id and count the users).